# Is wiringPiSetup BCM or BOARD?

Tags: gpio, python, wiringpi, wiring

I am using WiringPi to simulate PWM output to my GPIO pins. My problem is that I converted from the regular Rpi.GPIO library to WiringPi. I used BCM as GPIO mode but now WiringPi uses BOARD. How can I force WiringPi to uses BCM instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wiringPiSetup()` uses its own proprietary "wPi" numbering scheme. To change to BCM (GPIO), use `wiringPiSetupGpio()` instead.